# Auto-suppression list restarts triggered sends and delivers all queued emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, autosuppressionlist

Would someone be able to clarify what the following means please?

**Creating auto-suppression lists restarts triggered sends and delivers all queued emails.**

I need to edit an existing auto-suppression list to include transactional send classification (it's currently only valid against commercial send classification) and just want to be sure of the repercussions before I save it.

I understand Journey Builder is using triggered send definitions behind the scenes - how does the above affect the Journey Builder sends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notification means:
In order to refresh what the Triggered Sends might have to respect newly, or no longer respect - your new auto suppression configuration - the system will:

- 1 pause
- 2 apply changes
- 3 "Publish changes"
- 4 Restart

all triggered sends.

Every message request that trickles into your TS between 1 and 4 will stay in the queue during that "paused" time. The notification tells you that it will go through the queue after 4 so that no messages are stuck because of the change.

I showed the manual steps above for clarity's sake, but the system does all of that automatically in this usecase.

As you say, also journeys are based on the same infrastructure.
Since you do not have to do anything manually with normal TS, it would also be plausible that you have to do nothing in your journeys. I cannot give you a guarantee, but why I think it's plausible is because even the manual steps are simplified in journeys.  Instead of 1-4, you really just have to edit the email and hit save, JB streamlines steps 1-4 for you (but you still HAVE to do it to apply changes!).
So it would be really odd that in this particular case with Autosuppressions, where the system automates the whole thing for us, the already simplified Journeys would be left on the wayside.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation and detail @Jonas Lamberty

Comment: Hi @Jonas, were you telling that the auto suppression list wouldn't do steps from 1 to 4 for triggered email sends in a journey?

Comment: I said that it would be really odd that journeys (which are technically updated in the same way, just streamlined UI) would be different from triggered sends. They are based on the same infrastructure, I would expect the same behavior.

Comment: @JonasLamberty I think creating an auto-suppression list won't update/refresh the triggered sends in that way. Specifically, it won't do all steps from 1 to 4 but maybe only step 3. If you take a look at the triggered send in Email Studio after it finished the refresh, it only implied that these triggered sends were republished without were modified.  More over `Enabling this feature republishes the suppression list changes for the triggered send. Triggered send content isn’t updated` https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_create_auto_suppression_list.htm&type=5

Comment: So it won't help to update the email content in the journey, That's what I experienced and realized a few days ago